# How to transform a qiskit quantum circuit to a braket circuit?

Tags: qiskit, error-mitigation, amazon-braket, blind-quantum-computing

I have a quantum circuit in qiskit. Now I want to know is there any way that I can transform it to a braket circuit in AWS?
I want to use error mitigation in AWS. I have the circuit in qiskit. But as error mitigation in AWS only accept braket circuit I have to somehow transform the qiskit circuit to braket circuit. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know anything about braket, sorry if it's not useful, but if it supports openQASM then you can transform the qiskit circuit into openQASM string and back to braket maybe?

Comment: Ok. I will try to do that.

Comment: There is a similar question with newer answers.
[How to Properly Run a Circuit with Qiskit on AWS Braket](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/36990/how-to-properly-run-a-circuit-with-qiskit-on-aws-braket-attributeerror-awsdev/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this actually solves your problem but Amazon Braket recently released a Qiskit provider that you can install by `pip install qiskit-braket-provider`.
This tool let you to run your Qiskit `QuantumCircuit` by using Braket Python SDK:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_braket_provider import BraketLocalBackend

circ = QuantumCircuit()
# build your Qiskit circuit here
# ...

local_simulator = BraketLocalBackend()
task = local_simulator.run(circ, shots=1000)
```

Take a look at this link for more details: [Introducing the Qiskit provider for Amazon Braket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/quantum-computing/introducing-the-qiskit-provider-for-amazon-braket/).

Comment: Ok. Thanks! let me see

Answer (score 3):

You can transpile circuits from qiskit to braket using the [qBraid SDK](https://qbraid-qbraid.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/sdk/overview.html). For example:

```
from qbraid import circuit_wrapper
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qiskit_circuit = QuantumCircuit()
# ...

braket_circuit = circuit_wrapper(qiskit_circuit).transpile("braket")
```

See:

- qBraid SDK user guide: [Circuit Wrapper](https://qbraid-qbraid.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/sdk/circuits.html#circuit-wrapper), [Transpiler](https://qbraid-qbraid.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/sdk/circuits.html#transpiler)
- [qBraid SDK transpiler demo notebook](https://github.com/qBraid/qbraid-lab-demo/blob/0012288ad353bab001270900034b48be5f655c67/qbraid_sdk_transpiler.ipynb) (qiskit to braket in cells 12-14)

Note: Right now the qBraid SDK is only available on [lab.qbraid.com](https://lab.qbraid.com), but will be open-sourced very soon!

Comment: oky.. let me check

Comment: Sounds good, let me know if you need any additional guidance with setup!