# How to Properly Run a Circuit with Qiskit on AWS Braket, AttributeError: 'AwsDevice' object has no attribute 'configuration' by Current Implementation

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, grovers-algorithm, oracles, amazon-braket

**Description:**
I'm currently working on a project that involves running quantum circuits as a hybrid job on the aws tensor network simulator **'tn1'**. However, I'm encountering some issues when trying to execute my circuit

**Explanation of Gates in Circuit:**

The quantum circuit I'm trying to execute consists of a Grover oracle and a diffusion circuit. The Grover oracle includes various quantum gates such as **Hadamard (H), Controlled-NOT (CNOT), and rotational gates (e.g., Rz).** The diffusion circuit is composed of Hadamard gates, multi-controlled X gates, and single-qubit X gates.

**This is a how I create the the Grover oracle:**

```
def create_grover_oracle(target, num_qubits):
    qr = QuantumRegister(num_qubits)
    oracle_circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr)

    # to encode the target into the quantum state
    for i, bit in enumerate(address):
        if bit == '1':
            oracle_circuit.x(i)

    # apply CZ gates pairwise between adjacent qubits
    for i in range(num_qubits - 1):
        oracle_circuit.cz(i, i+1)

    # uncompute the encoding
    for i, bit in enumerate(target):
        if bit == '1':
            oracle_circuit.x(i)

    return oracle_circuit
```

**This is a how I create the diffusion circuit:**

```
def create_diffusion_circuit(num_qubits):
    qr = QuantumRegister(num_qubits)
    diffusion_circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr)

    # apply Hadamard gates to all qubits
    diffusion_circuit.h(range(num_qubits))

    # apply X gate to all qubits
    diffusion_circuit.x(range(num_qubits))

    # apply multi-controlled Z gate
    diffusion_circuit.h(num_qubits-1)
    diffusion_circuit.mct(list(range(num_qubits-1)), num_qubits-1)
    diffusion_circuit.h(num_qubits-1)

    # apply X gate again
    diffusion_circuit.x(range(num_qubits))

    # apply Hadamard gates again
    diffusion_circuit.h(range(num_qubits))

    return diffusion_circuit
```

**Current execute_quantum_circuit function that is causing the traceback:**

```
def execute_quantum_circuit(backend, circuit, shots=1000):
transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)
job = execute(transpiled_circuit, backend, shots=shots)

# Get the result of the job
result = job.result()

# Get the counts of measurement outcomes
counts = result.get_counts()

return counts
```

Error on the Cloudwatch logs: "**AttributeError: 'AwsDevice' object has no attribute 'configuration"**

**Need assistance:**

I would **appreciate any insights or guidance** on how to **create** the '**def**' to properly **configure and execute the quantum circuit** on AWS Braket using Qiskit as Hybrid Job, as well as any suggestions for debugging the AttributeError related to the AwsDevice object.

**P.S.:** I have also attempted using ***backend.run, job.execute, and task.run***, but encountered similar issues. i suspect it might be something related to I might not be using the correct parameters to execute the circuit or using incorrect commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run or transpile the qiskit circuit, you should define the `backend` as an `AWSBraketProvider` object, instead of the `AwsDevice` object. Below I show an example of how to run qiskit circuit on Amazon Braket, and how to submit it as a hybrid job.

```
from qiskit_braket_provider import AWSBraketProvider
from braket.jobs import hybrid_job
from braket.aws import AwsDevice
from braket.devices import Devices
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile

# @hybrid_job(device=AwsDevice(Devices.Amazon.TN1).arn)
def execute_quantum_circuit(circuit, shots=1000):
    backend = AWSBraketProvider().get_backend("TN1")
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)
    job = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=shots)
    
    # Get the result of the job
    result = job.result()
    # Get the counts of measurement outcomes
    counts = result.get_counts()

    return counts

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
execute_quantum_circuit(circuit)

# {'11': 507, '00': 493}
```

You should be able to run the same code with your diffusion circuit (however, there is an undefined variable `address` in the Grover circuit). In order to run the same code with hybrid job, you can simply uncomment the line starting with `@hybrid_job`.

For more examples, you can check out the "tutorials" folder in the qiskit-braket-provider repo ([link](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider/tree/main/docs/tutorials)).

Answer (score 1):

AWSBraketProvider is deprecated, and should be replaced by BraketProvider. After following fagd's answer and using BraketProvider, I am able to submit my jobs.